# Can/How to burn a .flac to an audio cd

Tags: server, command-line, cd, burning

This is a two part question.

**Can I burn .flac to audio cds?**

this might seem silly, but I was an early adopter of mp3 players. Think several years before Ipods. I never really had the need to burn too many cds. My girlfriend, however, keeps asking for cds for her cars cd player. I do have a huge collection. Most of which from artists who have a live recording policy. So sorry, no help on illegal downloads from me. So, can I give her great quality music, or will I need to convert these to mp3s? If this is the latter, what format might one suggest? Google seems to indicate that it is indeed possible.

**How do I burn these files from the command line?**

I am probably going to burn straight from my file-sever, which is headless machine (10.4)? I do have some .cue files, but ironically they seem to point to .wav files, where the files in question are .flac files. Am I able to utilize these .cue files?

Comment: How does your CUE sheet look like?

Comment: You can make data CD with MP3s (as FLACs probably wont play on any car CD player) or you can convert FLAC to WAV and create AudioCD. Choice is yours

Comment: 1. Cue sheet looks like every other proper cue sheet i've ever seen. Less the .wav in place of .flac. 2. How would I accomplish this from the command line?

Comment: I was asking because it was not clear to me if CUE sheet was referencing one "image" WAV file or separate files. However I'll provide you solution in couple of minutes/hours which I think would be best for your scenario.

Comment: ah, I see. its not a single file/img to such a .bin/.cue but instead I have multiple .flac files and the .cue sheet reads as multiple wav files. I have been able to convert to .wav simply by flac -d *.flac, but now I am searching for a command line alternative to write the disc. I did find a solution but it required me finding my write offset of my drive. I was going to research more after work. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rant:**

I would suggest you convert FLAC files to MP3 instead making AudioCD. Why?

1. You can't possibly notice difference between `lame -V 5` (or even lower) and original source listening in a car
2. You'll save yourself time in the process and save $ on plastic, as space needed would be ~10 times reduced this way, plus you wont need to browse for CDs to find single album ;)

**Procedure:**

1. **Convert FLACs to MP3 with lame** (lame recommends -V2, but in your
   case I'd go with -V5):

   `flac -d -c track.flac | lame -V 5 - track.mp3`

   example for processing all FLAC files in current folder:

   `for f in *.flac ; do flac -d -c "$f" | lame -V 5 - "${f%.*}.mp3" ;
   done`
2. **Convert MP3 folder structure to Joliet folder structure ISO image**
   After you have converted FLAC files to MP3 arange MP3s in folder structure (i.e. /artist/album/track) than make ISO image like this:

   `mkisofs -J -o /tmp/MP3-CD.iso /path to root of MP3 folder
   structure/`

   *Note: you can't go above 700MB, check for space first*
3. **Burn ISO image**

   `wodim dev=/dev/sg1 -dao speed=8 -eject /tmp/MP3-CD.iso`

   *Note: Use `wodim --devices` to check for your device.
   `dev=/dev/sg1` is valid for my system*

Voila

Comment: thanks, although your rant is wasted. While I may not be able to empirically argue point one, point two is mute. Space is hardly an issue. its not hard to do `rm *wav`, but the money on plastic is not a problem either due to my preference to make exact copies of some CDs, I do accept your notion on being able to add more tracks, but it does not apply in my case.... Also any thoughts on burning from the .cue's I have laying around. Anyway +1, I am going to leave this open a few days before accepting an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to read your comment, but you have your preferences. I won't be able to provide you walk through for making AudioCDs with your CUE sheets, because of my already posted answer. Look for cdrdao package, and accompanied documentation

Comment: well, I still didn't find precisely what I'm after, but I appreciate the help. Looking at `cdrdao` it looks rather simple, but i keep recieving the error Pregap Out of Range. I feel this may be an error with the .cue file, but its hard to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Something must be wrong with your CUE sheet(s) and there are many ways for it. I guess `cue2toc` will report same error. You could try `cdrtools` (cdrecord) as alternative, or just convert files to WAV and make AudioCD without CUE sheet

Answer (score 3):

In a directory that contains the .flac files you want to burn and nothing else:

```
for x in *.flac ; do flac -d "$x" ; done
wodim dev=/dev/cdrw -v -sao -useinfo -text -audio -pad driveropts=audiomaster *.wav
/bin/rm *.wav
```

(Assuming the location of your optical drive is `/dev/cdrw`.)

Answer (score 2):

For those that don't need to have a command line option, K3b and Brasero are supposed to be able to do it, however I could not make the latter work on my 12.04 64 bit machine, but it's working fine with K3b.

For this to work you need to:

- have a .cue file for your image, make one manually if you don't
- enable the K3b FLAC Decoder plugin
- install the FLAC++ library (sudo apt-get install libflac++6)

See also [the K3b requirements page](http://k3b.plainblack.com/requirements).

Comment: The last two points were unnecessary for me. I had a .cue file available. I installed the K3b and I was able to burn .cue file without changing any option - right out of the box.

Comment: Brasero works just fine for me on 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this old question as I was googling around with the same problem. I think this guide explains pretty well how to deal with .flac & .cue combos, especially with noncompliant .cue.

http://www.bitburners.com/blogs/3

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.