# how to burn music to CD using .cue and .flac files

Tags: cd, burning, flac

I want to archive my cd collection using [Rubyripper](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Rubyripper), but I am unable to burn the music back to disc using the .cue files Rubyripper generates. The previous post on SE - [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62168/can-how-to-burn-a-flac-to-an-audio-cd) - dodges the ability to recreate an accurate copy of the original disc. I have tried using K3b, but it does not recognize the .cue files as valid. I have tried Brasero, but it creates a disc filled with white noise, and I have tried cdrdao, and it also creates a disc with white noise. Does anyone know how to burn a .cue sheet associated with .flac files for each cd track back to disc? Is there an alternative besides using EAC on Wine?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into the *cdrecord* command line utilitity?

It has a *cuefile* parameter for CDRWIN compliant CUE sheets. You will have to convert the FLAC file(s) back to WAV (and fix the file naming inside the cue sheet).

Comment: perhaps add some commands how it really is done, so a driveby noob might find help too

Answer (score 1):

To burn a folder containing .flac files for individual tracks and a .cue sheet with info for the space between tracks, I used Soundconverter to convert the .flac files to .wav. I then changed all instances of ".flac" in the .cue file with ".wav." Brasero was then able to read the .cue file and burn the image to cd audio.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Download libmac2:
https://deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/m/monkeys-audio/libmac2_4.11-u4-b5-s7-dmo1_i386.deb

Download monkeys-audio:
https://deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/m/monkeys-audio/monkeys-audio_4.11-u4-b5-s7-dmo1_i386.deb

Install them using gdebi

After this, K3b recognises APEs easily.

Start it, click ‘New Audio CD Project’, locate the CUE file in the browser pane and double-click it.

You can play the tracks from within K3b and rip the files by clicking the blue arrow button.

---

Edited:

If Monkey’s Audio (APE) failed with a “unsupported format” error.

Download this file:

http://www.rarewares.org/debian/packages/unstable/k3b-plugin-monkeysaudio_3.1-0rarewares2_i386.deb

Install it using dpkg

After this, K3b recognises APEs easily.

Or try this:

At least two files that are essential to create an audio CD correctly.

Of the two files one has .flac extension and is usually called CDImage.flac, although it can be called any way.

The other file has a .cue extension and is similarly called CDImage.cue.
In this are the instructions to act on a specific .flac file (we must have both files in the same directory) and contains the precise instructions so that the application we use will record on a CD all the tracks with their exact duration and separated with a Interval of silence.

If we unzip the .flac file and get a .wav, a single track will appear and if we record it on a CD it will still have a single track. So we need both files.

The problems that we can find are related to the .cue file:

Usually in row 3, although it can be in another one but always before the location instructions and duration of the tracks, we have the name of the file on which to operate, it is CDImage.flac. WAVE then appears indicating that the application will unzip to .wav to burn to the CD.

If K3b does not recognize the .flac file, we unzip the .ape file with a converter (Soundconverter or Soundkonverter on Linux) to get a .wav file, which we have to put in the same folder as the .cue file. In the .cue file the image will appear as .flac, and we will only need to change the .flac extension to wav with a text editor. For example:

FILE "CDImage.ape" WAVE

We have to stay:

FILE "CDImage.wav" WAVE

If K3B recognizes the .flac file, but when trying to open the .cue the recording application gives us an error. It may happen that in this the extension is .wav. We also edit the .cue file and change the extension to .flac.

It may not match, the name of the .flac file with what is written in the .cue; Is solved Editing the file .cue and correcting the error. Whenever an error occurs, the .cue file must be carefully reviewed.

Fixed the problem, whatever, we opened the .cue file with the application K3b and will be recorded correctly on the CD.

Comment: I installed those packages, but now I get this error:  `Unable to handle the following files due to an unsupported format:
You may manually convert these audio files to wave using another application supporting the audio format and then add the wave files to the K3b project.
album.cue` So perhaps I need to introduce an additional step to convert the flac to WAVE.

Comment: @eric s: post edited.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to Soundconverter. I want to use .flac, not .ape, so I used Soundcoverter to change the .flac to .wav and replace ".flac" with ".wav" in the .cue file.  K3b still would not recognize the .cue file, but Brasero was able to burn from the .cue file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Asunder](http://littlesvr.ca/asunder/)?

It solved a compatibility issue that I had ripping CDs to .FLAC. I'm not sure it will solve your problem, but it's worth a try, that's a good software to have.

It can be installed using [Synaptic Package Manager](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/).

Comment: Asunder is for ripping only. My problem is burning related.